# In Excel, how do I access cells using fully-qualified numeric coordinates (worksheet, column, row)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have the indices of a cell in an Excel workbook: Worksheet, column, row (and yes, I know that Excel likes 1-based indices.)

Given those, what formua should I write to obtain the value of that cell?

Answer (score 3):

You may use the Excel
[ADDRESS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89):

> You can use the ADDRESS function to obtain the address of a cell in a
> worksheet, given specified row and column numbers. For example,
> ADDRESS(2,3) returns $C$2. As another example, ADDRESS(77,300) returns
> $KN$77. You can use other functions, such as the ROW and COLUMN
> functions, to provide the row and column number arguments for the
> ADDRESS function.
>
> Syntax: ADDRESS(row_num, column_num, [abs_num], [a1], [sheet_text])

Examples:

| Formula | Description | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =ADDRESS(2,3,1,FALSE,"[Book1]Sheet1") | Absolute reference to another workbook and worksheet | '[Book1]Sheet1'!R2C3 |
| =ADDRESS(2,3,1,FALSE,"EXCEL SHEET") | Absolute reference to another worksheet | 'EXCEL SHEET'!R2C3 |

You may use it in combination with the
[INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)
that can use the returned address to reference the cell.

You can use Excel INDIRECT together with the ADDRESS function to get a value in a certain cell on the fly.

To create an indirect cell reference, you embed the ADDRESS function
into an INDIRECT formula.
A trivial example is: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,3))`.

To reference worksheet by index number in Excel requires a name.
Unfortunately, this requires VBA code such as the following:

```
Function SheetName(number As Long) As String
    SheetName = Sheets(number).Name
End Function
```

The reference `SheetName(1)` will return the name of worksheet
number 1.

Comment: This won't work in my case, since I don't have sheet names, but rather indices.

Comment: This requires VBA. I added the code for a VBA function that can convert sheet index to name.

Comment: Since this requires VBA, one might as well write a simple VBA function which everything. Otherwise, when putting it all together (which your answer doesn't...), we get a very long and cumbersome string.

Comment: I agree - you might then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems you will need to write some VBA to get this functionality. Here's how to do it:

1. Bring up the VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) Window (e.g. by pressing Alt+F11).
2. Insert a new code Module (e.g. on the menu: Insert > Module).
3. A sub-window for the new module will come up. In the text area, insert the following code:

```
Function BY_SRC(sheet_index As Long, row_index As Long, col_index As Long) As Variant
 'Remember all these indices are 1-based
 BY_SRC = Worksheets(sheet_index).Cells(col_index, row_index).Value
End Function
```

and now, in your worksheet, you can write:

```
=BY_SRC(4, 2, 3)
```

as a cell formula to get the value of the 3rd column on the 2nd row of the 4th sheet.

Comment: +1 : better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If looking for a non-VBA and non-volatile solution to dynamically reference a cell by sheet, row and column number:

Switching INDIRECT for INDEX can make this non-volatile. INDIRECT is volatile and will recalculate at every opportunity possibly slowing down your workbook. If you have a limited number of sheets and know the sheets' names, you can

```
=CHOOSE(sheetnum, INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$Z, rownum, colnum), INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$Z, rownum, colnum), INDEX(Sheet3!$A:$Z, rownum, colnum), ...)
```

If you don't know the names of the sheets, then unfortunately you have no choice* but to use INDIRECT. You can however get a list of sheetnames using a macro 4.0 named range called [GET.WORKBOOK(1)](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/dynamically-list-excel-sheet-names). You still have to save the file in macro-enabled .xlsm format, but there isn't any need to use any VBA code.

*This statement isn't necessarily true. Their is another workaround. You implement your own sheet numbering scheme and an INDEX cell pickers in each sheet, then use 3D references to extract only the selected value. In A1 of each sheet, assign a unique sheet number. Now in B1 place:

```
=IF(sheetnum=A1, INDEX($A:$Z, rownum, colnum), 0)
```

In your summary sheet, define named ranges with workbook scope for your fully qualified numeric coordinates as used above. To get to final cell value:

```
=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet10!B1)
```

Note, you need to know at least the first and last sheet names (sheet1 and sheet10). Also this only works for numeric cell value and not text, but at least it is fully non-volatile!